# Data synchronizing theory

Tags: design-patterns, synchronization, theory

I'm looking for patterns how to synchronize data. We have multiple clients which should sync their data over an server.

But I always have problems like

- when an clients updates while another client is synching, he will never get it
- the client download its data which he has just uploaded

I have many different objects which can be changed, so one big journal for all is not a solution.

So I'm looking for ready to use patterns. Any links/books ?

Comment: What kind of data is being synchronized?

Comment: it's just about objects with an id and text. we have thousands of objects and not all clients can see the same.

Comment: Are your clients listening for update events from server or they just do checks in time interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks curious, but you can read OSPF routing protocol specification. The first task of this protocol is keep synchronized database with the routing tokens (Link State Advertisements).

Comment: it seems that this protocoll synches the whole state, the problem is that we have thousands of objects and not all clients can see the same

Comment: Yes of course the protocol has it's own specific, but I think the DB-exchange mechanism and the LSA flooding mechanism is good reference to create your own protocol with your own specific. Moreover the OSPF split all routing domain by the area with aggregation of the routing information on the borders. So you can't see full state of the routing domain if you are not participant of the area.